# DB2 - Multiple Result-Set Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, db2, dbeaver

So first off - I'm not sure if my problem lies with my DB2 code, or with my settings on DBeaver.

I have an issue when running the following code where only one result set is being displayed in DBeaver. My intention is to create a single procedure that returns 2 result sets to the UI. The purpose of this is so that I can run multiple scripts at once, and then have all of the result sets in the same location. I don't have any other software than DBeaver, so I can't exactly test this on any other management studio.

I'm doing this so that if I'm not in the office, someone else can easily run my queries. Let me know if any additional information is required / you have any questions. Table/column names have been made up for the question.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procedure_name (IN start_date date, IN end_date date) 
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 2   
BEGIN

DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
    SELECT 
        d.Student_NUM AS student_number,
        c.Teacher_NUM AS teacher_number,
    FROM dbo.c AS teachers
    INNER JOIN dbo.d AS student ON c.class_num= d.class_num;
    WHERE d.entry_date >= start_date and d.graduation_date < end_date


DECLARE C2 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
    SELECT 
        c.birth_date AS teacher_birth_date,
    FROM dbo.c AS teachers;

    OPEN C2;
    OPEN C1;   
END
```

I only get results for `C2`

If I switch the ordering of the `OPEN` I only get `C1`. It seems like it only returns the first `OPEN` cursor.

**UPDATE**

This is how the stored procedure is called, and the return set I am seeing. *NOTE*: the name of the return set is being displayed as `C` and I know I should be expecting `Result` and `Result-2`. (sorry for heavy redacting)

[image]

DBeaver version: 5.2.5

DB2 version: 9.5 Fix Pack 5

OS: Windows

Comment: Multiple result-sets from SQL-PL stored-procedure works correctly for me with Dbeaver 5.1.2 with Db2 v11.1 on Linux.  Each result-set appears in its own distinct tab in the GUI with default tab names "Results" and "Results-2".   So the result-sets *don't* and won't display on the same tab in case that was your expectation.

Comment: That wasn't my expectation. Looks like I'm on version 5.0.1, I'll try updating to latest and see what I get.

Comment: @mao Are you calling the procedure with `exec` or `call` ? It seems my return set isn't returning similarly with "Results" and "Results-2" but rather with the table name of C2

Comment: The only way to invoke an sproc for dynamic-SQL in Db2-LUW is to use CALL, and that's what I'm using in dbeaver. Any other method is specific to dbeaver , and is not native to Db2.

Comment: @mao I updated the question with how I'm calling the proc, and what the result set looks like. Also added version info.

Comment: How do you know your sproc is working? Have you verified both result-sets get returned to the Db2 command-line (db2 CLP), assuming you have a Db2-client installed on your workstation?  Could one result-set be empty (no rows)?  Although you are running an old unsupported Db2-version, I believe that version also let sprocs return multiple result-sets.  DEBUG your code perhaps?

Comment: I've confirmed both queries independently return the right results. I do not have a db2-client installed, only DBeaver.

Comment: Most likely that test is not sufficient. Try calling the sproc from the Db2 CLP *locally* at the Db2-server to verify the outputs (the Db2-server always has its own local Db2-client ). Since dbeaver clearly does work for multiple result-sets from an sproc with current versions, your issue is most likely something specific to your environment and your code.

Comment: I'll have to ask the database administrator for more information I guess then. Nobody has access to that server except him and one other person. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I found my issue.... :\ Under connection properties for the database, there is an "Edit Driver Settings" -> Adv. parameters -> "Driver supports multiple results" ..and the setting was disabled by default. Thanks for all the help @mao . If you want some rep feel free to post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Well done. I had checked my settings yesterday, and my version does not seem to have such a setting, and I believe I use default settings. Maybe older (or newer) versions had/have it. Anyway, issue is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by ballbreaker with a dbeaver configuration change.

This symptom will only appear if your database connection uses the "old" driver supplied with dbeaver called "DB2 LUW 8.x".  That driver is not automatically installed with current dbeaver versions (but can be manually downloaded), because a more recent driver is installed by default with current dbeaver versions.

If your database connection uses the driver called "DB2 LUW"  (as distinct from "DB2 LUW 8.x") then you will not experience this symptom.

If your connection uses the old driver (DB2 LUW 8.x), then Under connection properties for the database, there is an "Edit Driver Settings" -> Adv. parameters -> "Driver supports multiple results" . With the old driver, this setting was disabled by default, which caused the symptom. With the newer driver, there is no such setting.

Comment: The driver for reference is "DB2 LUW 8.x" with description of "DB2 LUW driver for older DB2 versions (8.x)"

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, with this particular environment the driver was installed manually to connect to our really old database (lol). Hopefully nobody has this same issue, but at least if they do, here's the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear, as said by @mao and @ballBreaker, must follow the next steps.

Ricght clic on "Edit Connection".

[image: Edit Connection]

Go to "Connection settings" section and clic "Edit Driver Settings" -> Adv. parameters -> "Driver supports multiple results".

[image: Edit Driver Settings]
[image: Adv. parameters]